# Didn't find class org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Cocos2d-x version 3 problems running Android test application.

I've followed the instructions how to create a new project using the cocos.py script.
This works fine. Then I follow the instructions running build_native.py. Import the Android test application to Eclipse. When I try to run it on a device I get.

05-09 10:54:42.363: E/AndroidRuntime(18170): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.testAndroid/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mycompany.testAndroid-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mycompany.testAndroid-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: did you add the path of the libcocos2dx project is `[your own game project folder]/cocos/2d/platform/android/java`

Comment: Make sure you have checked `Android dependencies` in `Build and Order` option under `Java Build Path` in Project Properties.

Answer (score 1):

You application has not org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity class.
Check, that required activity really exists.
For ex. if you proj.android/AndroidManifest.xml contains:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.mycompany.testAndroid"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0"
  android:installLocation="auto">
...
        <activity android:name=".AppActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize»>
```

Then you should have proj.android/src/com/mycompany/testAndroid/AppActivity.java:

```
package com.mycompany.testAndroid;
import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity;

public class AppActivity extends Cocos2dxActivity {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cocos console. It is quite useful tool.

I will describe example with simple project on linux.
You should have installed ant, python, sdk, ndk, jdk, jre, cocos2dx-3

First - you should create new project. Run in terminal
        cocos new TestProject -l cpp -p com.example.test

Open folder with project
        cd TestProject

Run project
        cocos run -p android

It will run sdk with HelloWorld example

Comment: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR]
Starting application.
running: '/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n "org.cocos2dx.rabbit/org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity"'

Starting: Intent { cmp=org.cocos2dx.rabbit/org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.cocos2dx.rabbit/org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity} does not exist.

Comment: Same error now, may you have any help how to solve it?